# How to select a child scope in a ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have made a user picker which acts like a group of checkboxes but without the checkboxes.  It works well however I am having one issue around clearing it after it has been used.

HTML:

```
<div ng-show="addTaskMenu">
  <div id="userPicker">
    <div ng-repeat="user in todo.users">
      <div class="userBar" ng-click="selectUser = !selectUser">
        <span ng-show="selectUser" class="icon-tick"></span>
        {{user.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="closeMenu()">Done</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.closeMenu = function(){
  this.addTaskMenu = false;
  // Something to select all the "selectUser" variables = false;
}
```

Is there a way I can set the `selectUser` variable to false from the `closeMenu()` function?  As in, can I select a child scope of an ng-repeat from a parent scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't access the child scope of ng-repeat, as you wouldn't know which element to manipulate. instead in closeMenu() you yould iterate all the users and deselect them:

```
$scope.closeMenu = function () {
  angular.forEach($scope.todo.users, function (user, index)  {
     user.selectUser = false;
  });
}
```

Then change in your view the `selectUser` to `user.selectUser` to have a state of each of the users:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in todo.users">
  <div class="userBar" ng-click="user.selectUser = !user.selectUser">
    <span ng-show="user.selectUser" class="icon-tick"></span>
    {{user.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you try

```
ng-click="selectUser($index)"
```

This is index of array "todo.users"